# Question on Integration Formula and Negative Result with the Plot of the Volume

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have created this code by modification from previous topics.

[image: volume]

I put the calculated volume on the volume plot. My questions are:

1. My plots are correct right?
2. My volume calculations are correct too right?
3. Why there will be negative volume? If I put the formula for vx(x) as r1 - r2 it will be negative. Should I put abs (absolute value) instead in the future? So I could careless If I put r1 - r2 or r2 - r1, the numbers is the same, only one has negative sign. What is the significant meaning of negative sign for volume? Do we need a careful thought when calculating volume through integration?
4. I do not use `sympy` is sympy better in calculating integral than numpy/scipy?

Thanks.. this is my code / MWE:

```
# Compare the plot at xy axis with the solid of revolution toward x and y axis
# For region bounded by the line x - 2y = 0 and y^2 = 4x
# Plotting the revolution of the bounded region 
# can be done by limiting the np.linspace of the y, u, and x_inverse values 
# You can determine the limits by finding the intersection points of the two functions.

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import sympy as sy
  
def r1(x):
    return x/2

def r2(x):
    return 2*(x**(1/2))

def r3(x):
    return 2*x

def r4(x):
    return (x/2)**(2)

def vx(x):
    return np.pi*(r2(x)**2 - r1(x)**2)

def vy(x):
    return np.pi*(r3(x)**2 - r4(x)**2)
  
x = sy.Symbol("x")
vx = sy.integrate(vx(x), (x, 0, 16))
vy = sy.integrate(vy(x), (x, 0, 8))

n = 200

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(14, 7))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(221)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(222, projection='3d')
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(223)
ax4 = fig.add_subplot(224, projection='3d')

y = np.linspace(0, 8, n)
x1 = (2*y)
x2 = (y / 2) ** (2)
t = np.linspace(0, np.pi * 2, n)

u = np.linspace(0, 16, n)
v = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, n)
U, V = np.meshgrid(u, v)

X = U
Y1 = (2 * U ** (1/2)) * np.cos(V)
Z1 = (2 * U ** (1/2)) * np.sin(V)

Y2 = (U / 2) * np.cos(V)
Z2 = (U / 2) * np.sin(V)

Y3 = ((U / 2) ** (2)) * np.cos(V)
Z3 = ((U / 2) ** (2)) * np.sin(V)

Y4 = (2*U) * np.cos(V)
Z4 = (2*U) * np.sin(V)

ax1.plot(x1, y, label='$y=x/2$')
ax1.plot(x2, y, label='$y=2 \sqrt{x}$')
ax1.legend()

ax1.set_title('$f(x)$')
ax2.plot_surface(X, Y3, Z3, alpha=0.3, color='red', rstride=6, cstride=12)
ax2.plot_surface(X, Y4, Z4, alpha=0.3, color='blue', rstride=6, cstride=12)
ax2.set_title("$f(x)$: Revolution around $y$ \n Volume = {}".format(vy))

# find the inverse of the function
x_inverse = np.linspace(0, 8, n)
y1_inverse = np.power(2*x_inverse, 1)
y2_inverse = np.power(x_inverse / 2, 2)

ax3.plot(x_inverse, y1_inverse, label='Inverse of $y=x/2$')
ax3.plot(x_inverse, y2_inverse, label='Inverse of $y=2 \sqrt{x}$')
ax3.set_title('Inverse of $f(x)$')
ax3.legend()

ax4.plot_surface(X, Y1, Z1, alpha=0.3, color='red', rstride=6, cstride=12)
ax4.plot_surface(X, Y2, Z2, alpha=0.3, color='blue', rstride=6, cstride=12)
ax4.set_title("$f(x)$: Revolution around $x$ \n Volume = {}".format(vx))

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Your plots are correct except for the plot at the upper right. The boundary is a little bit off. I change the `np.linspace` for `u` to `u = np.linspace(0, 8, n)`. However, the `np.linspace` of `u` for bottom right plot is correct, so it remains `u = np.linspace(0, 16, n)`. You can create different variable names for them, but I just simply reassign `u` again to `u` itself, and create an `X2`. I attached the complete code below.
2. Your volume calculations are correct.

> Upper right plot:
>
> [image]
>
> Bottom right plot:
>
> [image]

3. It is impossible to have negative volume. You can solve the integrate by hand first and compare it to the numerical results. You can check:
   https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/261244/is-there-a-fundamental-reason-that-int-ba-int-ab?rq=1
4. `SymPy` is for symbolic computation, but it can also do numerical integration, so does  `SciPy`. My guess is that they both have dependencies on `NumPy`. I think you are fine as long as you implement them correctly.

[image]

```
# Compare the plot at xy axis with the solid of revolution toward x and y axis
# For region bounded by the line x - 2y = 0 and y^2 = 4x
# Plotting the revolution of the bounded region 
# can be done by limiting the np.linspace of the y, u, and x_inverse values 
# You can determine the limits by finding the intersection points of the two functions.

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import sympy as sy


def r1(x):
    return x / 2


def r2(x):
    return 2 * (x ** (1 / 2))


def r3(x):
    return 2 * x


def r4(x):
    return (x / 2) ** (2)


def vx(x):
    return np.pi * (r2(x) ** 2 - r1(x) ** 2)


def vy(x):
    return np.pi * (r3(x) ** 2 - r4(x) ** 2)


x = sy.Symbol("x")
vx = sy.integrate(vx(x), (x, 0, 16))
vy = sy.integrate(vy(x), (x, 0, 8))

n = 200

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(14, 7))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(221)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(222, projection='3d')
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(223)
ax4 = fig.add_subplot(224, projection='3d')

y = np.linspace(0, 8, n)
x1 = (2 * y)
x2 = (y / 2) ** (2)
t = np.linspace(0, np.pi * 2, n)

u = np.linspace(0, 16, n)
v = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, n)
U, V = np.meshgrid(u, v)

X = U

Y1 = (2 * U ** (1 / 2)) * np.cos(V)
Z1 = (2 * U ** (1 / 2)) * np.sin(V)

Y2 = (U / 2) * np.cos(V)
Z2 = (U / 2) * np.sin(V)

#######################################

u = np.linspace(0, 8, n)  # linspace u for the upper right figure should be from 0 to 8 instead of 0 to 16
v = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, n)
U, V = np.meshgrid(u, v)

X2 = U  # created X2 here

Y3 = ((U / 2) ** (2)) * np.cos(V)
Z3 = ((U / 2) ** (2)) * np.sin(V)

Y4 = (2 * U) * np.cos(V)
Z4 = (2 * U) * np.sin(V)

ax1.plot(x1, y, label='$y=x/2$')
ax1.plot(x2, y, label='$y=2 \sqrt{x}$')
ax1.legend()

ax1.set_title('$f(x)$')
ax2.plot_surface(X2, Y3, Z3, alpha=0.3, color='red', rstride=6, cstride=12)
ax2.plot_surface(X2, Y4, Z4, alpha=0.3, color='blue', rstride=6, cstride=12)
ax2.set_title("$f(x)$: Revolution around $y$ \n Volume = {}".format(vy))

# find the inverse of the function
x_inverse = np.linspace(0, 8, n)
y1_inverse = np.power(2 * x_inverse, 1)
y2_inverse = np.power(x_inverse / 2, 2)

ax3.plot(x_inverse, y1_inverse, label='Inverse of $y=x/2$')
ax3.plot(x_inverse, y2_inverse, label='Inverse of $y=2 \sqrt{x}$')
ax3.set_title('Inverse of $f(x)$')
ax3.legend()

ax4.plot_surface(X, Y1, Z1, alpha=0.3, color='red', rstride=6, cstride=12)
ax4.plot_surface(X, Y2, Z2, alpha=0.3, color='blue', rstride=6, cstride=12)
ax4.set_title("$f(x)$: Revolution around $x$ \n Volume = {}".format(vx))

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```